# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I got this error and it's really puzzling

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of
>   undefined
>       at App.updateInfo (App.js:25)
>       at FormContainer.js:28

Those are these two

```
 nameOfCity: results.city.name,
```

and this

```
this.props.updateInfo(results);
```

The issue is that for example if I enter city "Zagreb" everything throws back ok. But anyother city I get this error. I tried restarting server, clearing cache but nothing works.

```
class App extends Component {

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Weather App</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
      <FormContainer label="Name of the city:"/>
      <WeatherInfo
          nameOfCity={this.state.nameOfCity}
          weatherDescription={this.state.weatherDescription}
          windSpeed={this.state.windSpeed}
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          maxTemperature={this.state.maxTemperature}
          minTemperature={this.state.minTemperature}
      />
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Form Container

```
class FormContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cityName: '',
        nameOfCity:'',
        weatherDescription:'',
        windSpeed:'',
        temperature:'',
        maxTemperature:'',
        minTemperature:''
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCityName = this.handleCityName.bind(this);
}

handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const SendForm = {
        cityName: this.state.cityName
    };
    console.log(SendForm);
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/weather?q=${SendForm.cityName}&units=metric&APPID=********`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
            this.setState({
                nameOfCity: results.city.name,
                weatherDescription: results.list[0].weather[0].description,
                windSpeed: results.list[2].wind.speed,
                temperature: results.list[0].main.temp,
                maxTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_max,
                minTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_min
            });
        });
}

handleCityName(value) {
    this.setState({ cityName: value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <label>{this.props.label}</label>
            <SearchBar
                name="CityName"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.cityName}
                placeholder="search"
                onChange={this.handleCityName}
            />
            <button type="submit"
                    className=""
                    value='Submit'
                    placeholder="Search" />
        </form>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export {FormContainer};
```

Search bar component

```
const SearchBar = (props) => (
<div>
    <label>{props.label}</label>
    <input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={(e)=>props.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
</div>
);

export default SearchBar;
```

and Weather Info component

```
const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
        <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
        <li>{props.windSpeed}</li>
        <li>{props.temperature}</li>
        <li>{props.maxTemperature}</li>
        <li>{props.minTemperature}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
);

export default WeatherInfo;
```

EDIT:-

Now after five submits in the row i get that same error. I did console.dir and i get

```
Object cod:"0" message:"Error" .
```

I checked the api i get 60 calls per minute

Comment: it just says that `results` do not have property `city` so `name` is `undefined`. Make `console.dir(results)` before and watch console

Comment: check `results.cod` - should be `'200'` if the request is OK - but yeah, log the whole results to see what's what

Comment: I added in my edit additional info